How can I take user input in Zig for this Fibonacci Series Generator
const std = @import("std");
const stdout = std.io.getStdOut().writer();
const print = std.debug.print;

pub fn fibonacci(n: i32) i32 {
    if (n <= 1) {
        return n;
    }

    return fibonacci(n - 1) + fibonacci(n - 2);
}

pub fn main() !void {
    var num: i32 = 15;
    var i: i31 = 1;

    var buf: [10]i32 = undefined;

    const stdin = std.io.getStdIn().reader();

    try stdout.print("enter a number: ", .{});

    if (try stdin.readUntilDelimiterOrEof(buf[0..], '\n')) |user_input| {
        num = std.fmt.parseInt(i32, user_input, 10);
    } else {
        num = @as(i32, 0);
    }

    // creating a loop
    while (i <= num) {
        print("{} ", .{fibonacci(i)});

        i += 1;
    }
}

It is the code I wrote to take user input for the number of terms to print the Fibonacci Series
and I get this following error:
> zig build-exe fibonacci.zig
fibonacci.zig:23:46: error: expected type '[]u8', found '*[10]i32'
    if (try stdin.readUntilDelimiterOrEof(buf[0..], '\n')) |user_input| {
                                          ~~~^~~~~
fibonacci.zig:23:46: note: pointer type child 'i32' cannot cast into pointer type child 'u8'
fibonacci.zig:23:46: note: unsigned 8-bit int cannot represent all possible signed 32-bit values
/home/alex/program/ziglang/lib/std/io.zig:187:18: note: parameter type declared here
            buf: []u8,
                 ^~~~
referenced by:
    posixCallMainAndExit: /home/alex/program/ziglang/lib/std/start.zig:617:37
    _start: /home/alex/program/ziglang/lib/std/start.zig:424:40
    3 reference(s) hidden; use '-freference-trace=5' to see all references
                                                                           

but I am unable to take user input normally like I can in C using the scanf() function.
Is there a better way to take input from user in Zig
I tried using the heap page_allocator instead of buff[] but still it showed some error

Why did you declare buf as an array of i32? As the error tells you, user input is written to an array of u8

First, the buf parameter of this function requires a []u8 type, but your code has:
var buf: [10]i32 = undefined;
After that, if you are using Windows, you will encounter another issue — Windows uses "\r\n" as the line ending, instead of just "\n". Therefore, you need to check for and remove the trailing "\r", or you will get an error: InvalidCharacter.
The final code is like this:
var buf: [32]u8 = undefined;
if (try stdin.readUntilDelimiterOrEof(buf[0..], '\n')) |user_input| {
    if (@import("builtin").os.tag == .windows) {
        const new_buf = std.mem.trimRight(u8, user_input, "\r");
        num = try std.fmt.parseInt(i32, new_buf, 10);
    } else {
        num = try std.fmt.parseInt(i32, user_input, 10);
    }
    print("num is:{}\n", .{num});
} else {
    num = @as(i32, 0);
}

Zig's official documentation provides examples of how to use the reader. You can check it out.
I'm not a native English speaker, so feel free to point out any grammatical mistakes.

thanks it's now working. It's vastly different than how C handles user input by just scanf(). It's an entirely different philosophy
